# Add an ImageLayer with ionic-leafletjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

I want to add an ImageLayer with the Ionic-leafletjs from [calendee](https://github.com/calendee). I have the map obj. in the angular $scope

Markers, center and so on are working.

**This is not working:**

```
$scope.map = {
      layers: {
        imageOverlay: {
          1: {
            imageUrl: 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
            imageBounds: [[47.062319, 7.614106], [47.062351, 7.614432]]
          }
        }
      }
```

This is the [ionic-leafletjs-map-demo](https://github.com/calendee/ionic-leafletjs-map-demo) which I used as ground.

Comment: Meanwhile, I made it: 
There where two things: first in the html tag its important not forgetting the

Comment: If you solved it, you should create an answer with the solution and accept it. :)